# Bulk Insert with large static data in Oracle

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, bulk, bulk-load

I have a simple table with one column of numbers. I want to load about 3000 numbers in it. I want to do that in memory, without using SQL*Loader. I tried

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO t_table (code) VALUES (n1)
   INTO t_table (code) VALUES (n2)
   ...
   ...
   INTO t_table (code) VALUES (n3000)
SELECT * FROM dual
```

But I fails at 1000 values. What should I do ? Is SQL*Loader the only way ? Can I do `LOAD` with SQL only ?

Comment: What is this `load` you're talking about? SQL*Loader? Is this a one off or something that's going to have to happen regularly? If regularly will the file structure always be the same>

Comment: yes, I realize that it is the SQL*Loader that I am talking about. so I don4t want to use it. I edited the auestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have an initial value of `n`.  If so, this code will populate `code` with values `n` to `n+2999` :

```
insert into t_table (code)
select (&N + level ) - 1
from dual
connect by level <=3000
```

This query uses a SQL*Plus substitution variable to post the initial value of `n`.  Other clients will need to pass the value in a different way.

---

> "Assume that I am in c++ with a stl::vector, what query should I
>   write ?"

So when you wrote `n3000` what you really meant was `n(3000)`.  It's easy enough to use an array in SQL.  This example uses one of Oracle's pre-defined collections, a table of type NUMBER:

```
declare 
    ids system.number_tbl_type; 
begin
    insert into t_table (code)
    select column_value
    from table ( select ids from dual )
    ; 
end;
```

As for mapping your C++ vector to Oracle types, that's a different question (and one which I can't answer).

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Assume that I am in c++ with a stl::vector<int>, what query should I write ?

Comment: @BaptistePernet - you posted a query, I gave you a query.